# Haskell exception can not be caught on Windows

Tags: windows, haskell, exception

When I typed following on ghci, the exception is raised:

```
Prelude> import Control.Exception
Prelude Control.Exception> readFile "test.txt" `catch` (const $ return "exception caught!" :: SomeException -> IO String)
"*** Exception: test.txt: hGetContents: invalid argument (invalid byte sequence)
```

I do not understand why the exception is not caught. I run the above with `stack ghci` command on Windows 7. 
("test.txt" file contains some random Japanese Letters encoded in UTF8, but I expect exception should be caught anyway)

Can someone explain why?

Comment: Does `test.txt` exist?  If yes, what are the contents.

Comment: Yes, text.txt exists. I'm currently on mobile, so I will update it later.  I assume the exception itself is raised due to code page mismatch. Default code page on Japanese machine is Shift-JIS while the file is encoded in UTF8. But I expect the exception should be caught anyway.

Comment: The issue is solved so I will not upload the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `readFile` returns a lazy `String`, it won't evaluate the file content until it is used, in this case, when ghci prints it. You can catch it by forcing to evaluate its content.

```
import Control.Exception
import Control.DeepSeq
(readFile "test.txt" >>= evaluate . force) `catch` (const $ return "exception caught!" :: SomeException -> IO String)
```

Answer (score 4):

This problem is caused by lazy IO and Windows' default locale encoding.

Contrary to your assumption, the file is actually read **after** `readFile "test.txt"`catch`(const $ return "exception caught!" :: SomeException -> IO String)`.
By lazy IO, the content of file is read only **when the result value is actually evaulated**.
And the exception you met is caused only when reading the content (explain below).

Evaluating forcibly the file make the `catch` function do catch:

```
> (print . length =<< readFile "test.txt") `catch` (const $ putStrLn "Exception caught" :: SomeException -> IO ())
Exception caught
```

In this example, the file is actually read when applying `length` function, then caught by the `catch` function.

In addition, the exception is caused because some (perhaps the first) character of `test.txt` is incompatible with the default character encoding of the handle,
which is CP932 in Japanese Windows.

Try inserting some ASCII characters before the invalid Japanese characters,
then you'd find the exception is really thrown when printing (actually evaluating the content of `test.txt`):

```
$ cat .\test.txt
abc介
$ stack exec ghci
> import Control.Exception
> readFile "test.txt" `catch` (const $ return "exception caught!" :: SomeException -> IO String)
"abc\33673*** Exception: test.txt: hGetContents: invalid argument (invalid byte sequence)
```

If you can read Japanese, see the first section of https://haskell.jp/blog/posts/2017/windows-gotchas.html, written by me! :)

Comment: I understand the cause! Thank you for answering the question in detail.